# Regex to get value from variable String

Tags: regex

i'm trying to extract a value from a Cookie.  cookies are organized with [name]=[value] pairs separated by a ';'.  so if i have a cookie string like so:

```
username=user;password=pass;session="4341234556";
```

in this example, i only want the value '4341234556' without the quotes.

the value of the session variable is, of course, different for each request made.  how can i get just the value of session with a regular expression (without the quotes)?  keep in mind that the ordering of the variables is not guaranteed to be the same each time it is returned.

also, i would like to ignore any whitespace characters NOT contained in the value.

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all those key value pairs exist? Are they all in a single line? Is the value you want to get always enclosed in double quotes, or can it be enclosed in single quotes as well?

Comment: @GeorgeTs the only K=V pair guaranteed to exist is 'session="stuff"'.  yes, they are all received on a single line, but that is not guaranteed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a regular "consuming" pattern (requires match group access)

`session="([^"]+)" //sessionid is in $1`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKoa3p/2)

with a lookbehind (entire match is the sessionid, no match groups required):

`(?<=session=")[^"]+`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/CksJZA/2)

Comment: this worked great (the second solution).  however, is there a way to write this such that it will return the same value even if the quotation marks do not exist?  [edit: nevermind, i figured that one out.  thanks so much!]

Comment: if only number, u can replace [^"]+ to \d+

Comment: "(?<=session=)"?([^"]+)" (remove quotes) with optional quotes.